# How do i find a child div winthin a parent with the mouse, div has only a classname

Tags: jquery, class, html, mouse

Sorry if this is has already been ask but I can't find the exact solution that I need.

I am a noob to jquery and am making a newspaper layout form. I can make new divs within the layout canvas without a problem using this code

```
function makeSplashBlockdiv() {
    $("#canvas").append('<div class="SplashBlock" class="bar">Splash Block 700X250</div>')
    $(".SplashBlock").draggable({
        containment: "#canvas",
        scroll: false,
        grid: [10, 10]
    }, {
        cursor: "move",
        cursorAt: {
            top: 125,
            left: 350
        }
    })
}​
```

There are other divs of different size and class names.  I am not using id's because the program can create multiple divs of the same type so id

All of these divs are placed in a div called `#canvas`.

I need to be able to select a div with the mouse and delete it, the closest I can come it to find which div is with this code but nothing happens.

```
$("#canvas").click(function(event) {
    $("#log").html("clicked: " + event.target.className);
```

I know that there should be a click handler, but i have not been able to figure this part out.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: bind the click event to the class of the divs, not to the canvas that holds them. That way you can use `$(this)` to access the clicked div and just remove it (e.g. `$(this).remove()`)

Comment: I got it, the problem was that I didn't place the jquery  inside the canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the click event to the class of the divs, not to the canvas that holds them.

e.g.

```
$(".divclass").click(function(){});
```

That way you can use `$(this)` to access the clicked div and just remove it

e.g.

```
$(".divclass").click(function(){
   $(this).remove()
});
```

Comment: No, much better to do what the OP is already doing (event delegation).

Comment: I just this and it doesn't work. Where should I be placing this code?

Comment: put it into the `$(document).ready()` function. Just make sure your `div`s actually have the class that I called `.divclass`

Comment: I got it, the problem was that I didn't place the jquery inside the canvas, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options for you:

1) Use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) on `event.target`:

```
$("#canvas").click(function(event) {
    var theDiv = $(event.target).closest('div');
    // ...
});
```

That will find the div the mouse was clicked on. `closest` starts with the element in the set and finds the first element that matches the selector, working up through parent elements as necessary.

2) Alternately, you could have jQuery do that for you, by changing your `click` handler to use event delegation explicitly, via [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate):

```
$("#canvas").delegate("div", "click", function(event) {
    var theDiv = $(this);
    // ...
});
```

In newer versions of jQuery, you can use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) instead (note the order of arguments changes);

```
$("#canvas").on("click", "div", function(event) {
    var theDiv = $(this);
    // ...
});
```

...although personally I prefer the clarity of `delegate`.

Comment: I put the above code just after the <body> tag.  This is a cut and paste of the code i put in.   <script>
$("#canvas").click(function(event) {
    var theDiv = $(event.target).closest('div');

alert ("the div is " + theDiv);
});
</script> I didn't see any out put when I clicked on a div

Comment: @Chris: *"I put the above code just after the <body> tag."* Then your element with the `id` `"canvas"` won't exist yet when the code runs, and so the code can't set an event handler on it. Either move the `script` element to the *end* of the document, just above the closing `</body>` tag, or use jQuery's [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready) feature (but there's really no need to use `ready` if you control where the script tags go on the document).

Comment: I got it, the problem was that I didn't place the jquery inside the canvas.  Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

The following will add a `selected` class to all clicked divs.

```
function makeSplashBlockdiv() {
    var $myNewDiv = $('<div class="SplashBlock" class="bar">Splash Block 700X250</div>');

    $myNewDiv.click(function () {
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    });

    $("#canvas").append($myNewDiv);

    $(".SplashBlock").draggable({
        containment: "#canvas",
        scroll: false,
        grid: [10, 10]
    }, {
        cursor: "move",
        cursorAt: {
            top: 125,
            left: 350
        }
    });
}​
```

Then you can manipulate all of the selected divs via `$("#canvas .selected")`.